# Confusion about with statement python

Tags: python, with-statement, file-management

I have a question regarding the use of `with` statements in python, as given below:

```
with open(fname) as f:
    np.save(f,MyData)
```

If I'm not mistaken this opens the file `fname` in a secure manner, such that if an exception occurs the file is closed properly. then it writes `MyData` to the file. But what I would do is simply:

```
np.save(fname,MyData)
```

This would result in the same, `MyData` gets written to `fname`. I'm not sure I understand correctly why the former is better. I don't understand how  this one-liner could keep the file "open" after it has ran the line. Therefore I also don't see how this could create issues when my code would crash afterwards.

Maybe this is a stupid/basic question, but I always thought that a cleaner code is a nicer code, so not having the extra `with`-loop seems just better to  me.

Comment: Presumably in `np.save(fname,MyData)` you are allowing np to handle the opening and closing of the file instead of handling it yourself.

Comment: ``np.save`` is "special" in that takes either an open file or a path. Most APIs are more opiniated about what is and isn't their responsibility – a ``with`` statement makes sense for them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`numpy.save()` handles the opening and closing [in its code](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.21.0/numpy/lib/npyio.py#L458-L530), however if you supply a file descriptor, it'll leave it open because it assumes you want to do something else with the file and if it closes the file it'll break the functionality for you.

Try this:

```
f = open(<file>)
f.close()
f.read()  # boom
```

See also the `hasattr(file, "write")` ("file" as in **descriptor** or "handle" from file, buffer, or [other IO](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html)) check, that checks if it's an object with a `write()` method and judging by that Numpy only ***assumes*** it's true.

However NumPy doesn't guarantee misusing its API e.g. if you create a custom structure that's a buffer and **doesn't** include [`write()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.RawIOBase.write), it'll be treated as a path and thus crash in the [`open()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) call.

Comment: Thanks, this clears things up. To check if I understand better, and put it in layman's terms: The `with` statement is a nice and easy way to open, read/write/whatever you want and close a file in the proper order, without you as user/implementer having to worry about it (too much). `np.save()` does this behind the scenes (a bit crudely, perhaps). The `with` statement seems in that case  more useful when using files directly, so without numpy as medium.

Comment: @User123456789 Kind of, but not exactly. When possible you should use the `with` statement because the code maintainer/creator intended it to use the [`__enter__()` and `__exit__()`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/e5862f79c16e28f1ec51d179698739a9b2d8c1d2/Lib/_pyio.py#L519) functions of such class. Nevertheless, it's solely up to you whether you do or do not want that code to be executed and you'll bear consequences for that as well be it crash or simply silly errors in case the code creator expects some context setup via `with` context manager. :)

Comment: In the `numpy.save()` context, it's up to you whether you want to handle the file by yourself (thus using `with` or just providing a file descriptor) or if you want to leave NumPy responsible for handling and therefore any potential leaks (using only `numpy.save(<path>)`).

Comment: Thanks! I asked the  question since I waned to move away from numy.save(), and to me this made clear why I should use the `with` statement. And I'll use it, especially since I know how I work ;).